# Django: not able to cut an array

Tags: django-templates

I'm using a Wordpress plugin to show the dimensions of [variable products](http://witchphotographer.dreamhosters.com/shop/bridgnorth/bridgnorth-queens-parlour-witches-and-dragons/). However, [this line](https://github.com/alaarihan/woo-variations-table/blob/master/woo-variations-table.php#L285)

> {{entry[column.key]}}

is outputting this:

> { "length": "", "width": "69.2", "height": "32" }

When I want just:

> 69.2 x 32 cm

Brand new to Django, I've tried every version of cut I can think of. Here's just one example:

> {{entry[column.key]|cut:'{ "length": "", "width": "'}}

Even the the easiest does absolutley nothing:

> {{entry[column.key]|cut:':'}}

I thought I'd simply cut out the strings I don't want, hacking with a sharp knife. I'm sure there's a more elegant way, but cut would do for this newbie. But, I cannot understand why I cannot cut anything out. I guess it's because it's an array, but to my eyes, it's outputting as a string, which I should be able to chop up, as I like.

I'd ask the writer of the plugin but the support has slowed to no answers. I'll go back there and answer this problem, once I've figured it out, for footsteps in the snow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `{{entry[column.key][width]}} x {{entry[column.key][height]}} cm`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Your answer was merely missing the quotes. Genius :-) Be happy for ever.

> {{entry[column.key]['width']}} x {{entry[column.key]['height']}} cm.